# XAML - Synchronize same animation on different rows of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm using a DataGrid to show some elements of a collection:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItemsList}" [...]
```

what I want is that if a particular column of a Row is '1', that row starts to blink. I can achieve this behaviour in this way:

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="rowBlink" x:Name="Blink" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="40" SpeedRatio="1">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="Orange" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>    
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Acked}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="blinkStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource rowBlink}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Acked}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="blinkStoryBoard" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The problem is that the animation are not in synch for each row of the grid. If a row is added later, it will blink not in phase with the others. Is there a way to synch the animation?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a solution to your exact question, but potentially a workaround that will achieve your intended effect:

Instead of having each row blink on its own, maybe you can have the background of the DataGrid blink? Those rows which *shouldn't* be animated can have their BackgroundColor set to your default color, and the animated rows can have their background set to Transparent (so you can see the background).

There may be a few issues, such as having edges of the DataGrid showing the BackgroundColor animation as it blinks, but it may be worth a try. I'd run it myself, but I don't have my environment set up on this machine...if I get a chance tonight I'll run a test and post here again.